# Support for EnterpriseDB in new (>5.0.0) flyway versions?

Tags: flyway, enterprisedb

Flyway 5.0.0 Release Notes say:

> Important note for EnterpriseDB, Vertica, SolidDB, Phoenix and
>   Greenplum: Support for these databases has been kept back and will be
>   integrated later in the Flyway 5.0 series. You can keep using Flyway
>   4.2.0 until then.

Can someone enlighten the plans a little? Does not look like EnterpriseDB support has been added in one of the 5.x.x versions. (We are using Flyway 4.2.0 but at some point to make an upgrade will be necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These databases weren't added in 5.x but are on the backlog for the new team. You can track EnterpriseDb specifically at https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2399 and there are other issues for the remaining databases in that list. Do go and give a thumbs-up there as that helps the team prioritise!

It is also possible to add support oneself and PRs will be welcomed - take a look at https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/contributingDatabaseSupport